# Custom drawable angle android

Tags: android, android-drawable

First of all this is not a duplicate question. I want to achieve this custom design in android using drawable. How to achieve the arc effect as in the image??

[image]

Till now what i have done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-5"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="100%"
            android:toDegrees="50">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/light_pink" />
                <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="50dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="10%"
            android:pivotY="-100%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/light_pink" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Output: [image]

**Issue:**
The image is overlapping the background. I have also set **clipChildren** to the parent layout but no effects.

**My Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_arc"
        android:clipChildren="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image_male" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just for info: I have SVG for the same but don't know how to prevent overlapping.

Comment: did you see [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/8af0092e2d7409e79779af396d63ca4146f1fb21/v4/java/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.java)? if so, make similar custom `Drawable` (for details refer to `draw(Canvas)` method)

Comment: i know there must be a way with draw method of canvas and also i have tried to achieve with same but i am not so good with this.

Comment: well, i will not write it for you: you have to learn `Canvas` API first

Comment: i have tried the same for almost 2 days. but not be able to achieve

Comment: simply read `android.graphics.Path` and `android.graphics.CornerPathEffect` documentation

Comment: what is unclear in `Path` class documentation?

Comment: did you try `Path#lineTo` / `Path#rLineTo` methods?

Comment: Thanks for your help but i am using https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView this. It has option to use drawables as custom view

Comment: https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView#using-path-with-elevation

Comment: https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView#using-drawable-no-elevation

Comment: so you know what to do now

Comment: yes. just use this awesome lib :P

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution. Just replace the colours.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/top_rl_gradient"/>
<item
    android:bottom="-200dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-300dp"
    android:top="200dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-10"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

You can adjust the angle and the height of the drawable form the rotate tag. Hope this helps you.

Comment: it is just a background. you can replace it with color using @color/your_color

Comment: The main issue is image is still overlapping the background

Comment: as you can see in the desired result there are round corners as well.

Comment: from the library i can't achieve this